# How to safely use SmtpClient.SendAsync in Multithreaded application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

In my application, I am using `ActionBlock` from Dataflow library, to send out email alerts using [`SmtpClient.SendAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb90y5w7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, which does not block calling thread.(`ActionBlock` is getting it's data from `BufferBlock`, and blocks are tied together using `bufferBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock)`). However, this method will throw `InvalidOperationException` if another `.SendAsync()` call is in progress.

According to MSDN [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), there is `public event SendCompletedEventHandler SendCompleted` that is raised when send operation completes.

How do I make sure, that race between threads (or `Tasks`) spawned by `ActionBlock` will not cause `InvalidOperationException` to be thrown ?

One thought, I have so far, is to add to my class(that sends out emails) private lock around `SendAsync()` call and private function that will be assigned to `SendCompleted` event. When the thread reaches `SendAsync()` it obtains the lock, and when the event is raised, private function unlocks the lock, allowing other threads to obtain lock, and progress.

Answer (score 4):

Create one `SmtpClient` for each send operation. That way there is no need to synchronize anything. Simply enclose it in `using` to clean up.

Answer (score 2):

You should simply use `SendMailAsync` instead. It will start with calling `SendAsync` and complete when `SendCompleted` is raised.

To make sure only 1 message is sent at each moment you can use `SemaphoreSlim` set to 1. It's basically an `AsyncLock`.

However, this will limit you parallelism as you can only perform one operation at a time. You can simply use many different clients. If not one per call then use some resource pool and then you can have concurrency but still keep each client thread-safe.

```
var client = _smtpClientPool.Get();
try
{
    await client.SendMailAsync(...)
}
finally
{
    _smtpClientPool.Put(client);
}
```