# ASP.NET - Send bulk mail in parallel - fastest and most efficient way

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I want to send a newsletter to our site's registered users - more than 100000

Today, I send the mails in a simple `for` loop, which is very heavy and slow.
I want it to finish the process as fast as possible (even if the process would run in the background and didn't bother the users' UI)

I tried `TPL`, `Async`, `smtpClient.SendAsyncMail()` and more, but never could actually create a working example that proves that these systems work faster (or work at all).
I've read many posts and explanations using thread, but they seem to be old, deprecated or irrelevant, since there are new technologies I surely don't know of.

***Could you please tell me what is the most efficient and fastest way to send multiple emails in parallel? Could you show me an example that works?***

**UPDATE 20/06/2018**

Each email is different for each user. Therefore a BCC solution is irrelevant for me.

I will specify my question a little more:
I only focus on the high-level where I use a sending function, such as ASP.NET `smtpClient.Send()` to send the mails to the SMTP.

I ignore for now the part of the SMTP itself. I have a great SMTP server that knows how to handle the queuing.

The main pitfall right now is the Send function that uploads the bytes to the SMTP server in ASP.NET.
That's where I couldn't find a way to send faster. (It is needles to say that if I buy a stronger server, even an iterative method will work faster)

But I want a scalable solution - a smarter one, where I can send in parallel huge amounts of mails.

**UPDATE 28/06/2018**

***Apparently a parallel solution will not solve my problem. As explained by @Terry Carmen and others, I may have to look at other bottle necks in the process. Thank you all for helping!
What a great community!!!***

Comment: The fastest way to send multiple emails differs between machine and machine, and differs depending on your use case. It is very difficult to answer your question without knowing what you actually tried, what machine you are using and whether or not your emails are related - meaning, whether or not they will block each other.

Comment: Each email is different for each user. I only focus on the high-level where I use a sending function to send the mails to the SMTP. I ignore for now the part of the SMTP itself. I have a great SMTP server that knows how to handle the queuing, but the problem is the Send function that uploads the bytes to the SMTP server in ASP.NET. There is my pitfall where I couldn't find a way to send faster. It is needles to say that if I buy a stronger server, even an iterative method will work faster, but I want a scalable solution - a smarter one, where I can send in parallel huge amounts of mails.

Comment: If you're hitting the maximum throughput of your mail server, then what solution would there be other than increasing this maximum?

Comment: @CodeCaster I am not talking about the throughput of my mail server. My mail server can handle much more. The problem is the basic sending such as:

for each m in mails
      smtpClient.send(m)
next

Comment: Yes you are, you claim _"The main pitfall right now is the Send function that uploads the bytes to the SMTP server"_. If you can't make that go faster, you can't send mails faster. Unless you try it in parallel.

Comment: @CodeCaster Even if It takes 500 ms to send the data to the SMTP, if I have 100,000 users then it will still be slow. Your comment on the parallel solution, that is what I am looking for. But I do not know how to make it work. That is what I want to know

Comment: Is the mail server a physically separate machine? If so, could it be that there is a slow network connection slowing down the transfer of emails to it?

Comment: @AndrewMorton It is a separate machine but there is no problem with the network. My question is how to send mails in parallel in ASP.NET. The other parameters, thought important and also relevant, are not related to my specific question.

Comment: "(It is needles to say that if I buy a stronger server, even an iterative method will work faster)" That isn't guaranteed. It's entirely possible that your SMTP server has a rate limit configured. You keep going back to "parallel" but the chances of it actually helping are not good.

Comment: @Terry Carmen i was trying to say that regardless of stronger or weaker hardware and better connection speeds, how it would be possible to send bulk mails in a better way than a simple 'for' loop. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, you can speed it up by finding the slow part and fixing it if possible. You'll need to take measurements and find out where and why it's slow. Since each email is unique, you will always need a loop of some sort, somewhere. If you have SQL Server, you can send the messages right from the server, although I don't think that will fix your problem.

Comment: @TerryCarmen The SQL Server solution doesn't seem to be what I need. Because each mail is unique, a loop is needed to send each mail. I want to know what ASP.NET method/library/architecture allows me to connect to the smtp client once, then send all the mails in parallel or in a certain pipeline without having to reconnect to the smtp client each time, being always the same smpt server I connect to

Comment: The SMTPClient has no functionality for sending in parallel. It does have a SendAsync, but this only allows your app to remain responsive and hot hang while waiting for the mail server response. The messages are still sent one at a time. You can should be able to keep the SMTPCLient object open and run any number of mailmessages through a single instance, but they will not be in parallel.

Comment: @Terry Carmen I see... I wonder if there is another programming language that does have an SMTPClient that works in parallel. Do you happen to know such?

Comment: You can do it in .Net. It just requires that you start a new thread for each parallel task.

Comment: @TerryCarmen You mean for each parallel task, which would be a single mail? If I send each mail in a separate thread it will force me to initiate the SMTP client for each thread, so it may be slower than iterating the sending but with only one instantiation of the SMTP client. Am I right? If not - Why is it? Could you please show me a simple code example of your solution?

Comment: " If I send each mail in a separate thread it will force me to initiate the SMTP client for each thread," That's correct. I don't believe it will help with performance, but it is possible to do. I don't do asp.net so you'll have to do some googling or check with someone else for examples.

Comment: @TerryCarmen I actually would like to know, from your experience in your programming languages, if any of those languages do allow to connect to an SMTP Client once and then send in parallel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636168/how-to-safely-use-smtpclient-sendasync-in-multithreaded-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the users as BCC recipients to the message and let the mail server do the work.

The mail server probably has a BCC limit, so you may have to see what the server's limit is and batch the requests.

**edit**

Regarding "sending in parallel"

You're looking for the wrong answer. If your machine takes X seconds to produce Y emails, running them "in parallel" won't fix anything . The most you would do is split the generation between several cores, which might improve performance a little, but is almost certainly not the problem.

You need to see "what the actual slow part is". It might be your disk or CPU or network connection, or database server or possibly a rate limit setting on the mail server. The actual SMTPClient object is almost certainly not the issue.

**another edit**

You can try sending in parallel by running separate instances of SMTPClient in separate threads; However this is unlikely to actually help you.

As mentioned before by myself and others, you are assuming that parallel send is some sort of magic bullet. It's not. There is something that is rate-limiting you and it's almost certainly not that you're single threaded.

Comment: This cannot be done because each one of the mails is different. Every user receives a specific content with its name and own content